WARNING :Y ou exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details, OpenAI API key
I am doing this :
query_engine = PandasQueryEngine(df=haa_develChronologies, verbose = True)
response = query_engine.query("provide me time stemp for observations C0392747")
Do you know how to fix it :even i paid 10$ for API
WARNING:llama_index.llms.openai.utils:Retrying llama_index.llms.openai.base.OpenAI._chat in 0.6463387303888469 seconds as it raised RateLimitError: Error code: 429 - {'error': {'message': 'You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details. For more information on this error
I tried changing API keys and different accounts.

Read the response headers for details on your rate limit availability and usage. $10 only buys so many tokens.

Does this answer your question? OpenAI API error 429: "You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details"
